# multiple if conditions in r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have been working on this problem, but failed to solve it. I know the answer might be very easy, but I could not solve it and could not find how to solve it from other similar questions as well.

I have got the following data.frame:

```
region    group   probs1   probs2   probs3   probs4     weights
   1        2       0.2       0.3     0.4       0.1        NA
   2        4       0.3       0.4     0.15      0.15       NA
   3        3       0.4       0.1     0.3       0.2        NA
   4        1       0.7       0.1     0.1       0.1        NA
   5        1       0.2       0.3     0.4       0.1        NA
   6        2       0.6       0.1     0.1       0.2        NA
   7        3       0.7       0.1     0.1       0.1        NA
   8        4       0.3       0.2     0.1       0.4        NA
   9        3       0.2       0.1     0.1       0.6        NA
  10        1       0.1       0.2     0.1       0.6        NA
```

What I am going to do is to create a new column in the data.frame called "weights" that is calculated as if group==1, then weights=probs1/probs1. If group==2, then the weights=probs1/probs2. If group==3, then the weights=probs1/probs3. If group==4, then the weights=probs1/probs4.

I used different types of codes like, `ifelse`, `if....else`, `dplyr`, but I failed. In fact, may codes only create the weights for weights=probs1/probs1 and apply it for all the regions, regardless of the group.

May someone please help me to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(weights = case_when(
        group == 1 ~ probs1 / probs1,
        group == 2 ~ probs1 / probs2,
        group == 3 ~ probs1 / probs3,
        TRUE ~ probs1 / probs4))
#   region group probs1 probs2 probs3 probs4   weights
#1       1     2    0.2    0.3   0.40   0.10 0.6666667
#2       2     4    0.3    0.4   0.15   0.15 2.0000000
#3       3     3    0.4    0.1   0.30   0.20 1.3333333
#4       4     1    0.7    0.1   0.10   0.10 1.0000000
#5       5     1    0.2    0.3   0.40   0.10 1.0000000
#6       6     2    0.6    0.1   0.10   0.20 6.0000000
#7       7     3    0.7    0.1   0.10   0.10 7.0000000
#8       8     4    0.3    0.2   0.10   0.40 0.7500000
#9       9     3    0.2    0.1   0.10   0.60 2.0000000
#10     10     1    0.1    0.2   0.10   0.60 1.0000000
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "region    group   probs1   probs2   probs3   probs4     weights
   1        2       0.2       0.3     0.4       0.1        NA
   2        4       0.3       0.4     0.15      0.15       NA
   3        3       0.4       0.1     0.3       0.2        NA
   4        1       0.7       0.1     0.1       0.1        NA
   5        1       0.2       0.3     0.4       0.1        NA
   6        2       0.6       0.1     0.1       0.2        NA
   7        3       0.7       0.1     0.1       0.1        NA
   8        4       0.3       0.2     0.1       0.4        NA
   9        3       0.2       0.1     0.1       0.6        NA
  10        1       0.1       0.2     0.1       0.6        NA", header = T)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But, my data.frame is too big. I just provided a very short sample of it. And, I just cannot see any change in the data frame. I mean, the wights in my data.frame is still NA.

Comment: In deed, my question is who I can see it in the my data.table and not in the console?

Comment: @Eshmel You need to save the `dplyr` chain as a new object, just like in basic R: `df.new <- df %>% mutate(...)`. I'm not sure what you you mean by your `data.frame` is too big. This will work with any number of rows.

Comment: I used a same approach to create the mean of a variable for these groups as follows:

Comment: I used a same approach to create the mean of a variable (mid population) for these 4 groups. The main part of the code was this:   `groupadmit == 1 ~ mean(mid_pop)` that was repeated for four other groups (just like your code above). But, again it created the mean for only the first group for all the rows (observations). My you please help me to solve this problem as well? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `dplyr` package to solve this, although it is possible without that also.

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame <- data_frame %>%
  mutate(
    weights = ifelse(group==1,probs1/probs1,
              ifelse(group==2,probs1/probs2,
              ifelse(group==3,probs1/probs3,
              ifelse(group==4,probs1/probs4,NA))))
  )

print(data_frame)
```